# AngularJS transclude doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

This example works well with AngularJS 1.1.5 (it's going to append it into div), but with 1.2.5 not (it's leaves html content without append).

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-transclusion-basics

```
app.directive("panel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="panel" ng-transclude>This is a panel component</div>'
    }
})
```

AngularJS 1.1.5: http://plnkr.co/edit/BLe56D9YZxSIAiJ31wW0 ("This is..." appears as expected) AngularJS 1.2.5: http://plnkr.co/edit/h6dUrXXXBOQUtzsJqT4S ("This is..." doesn't appears)

In 1.1.5 "transclude: true" works as expected (text is appended to panel), but in > 1.2.0 not.

Any help?

Comment: In Angular v1.3.15 ng-transclude still doesn't work, but in 1.1.5 it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your template in the directive to:

```
template: '<div class="panel" >This is a panel component</div><div ng-transclude></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the exact behavior is now captured like so:

```
template: '<div class="panel"> This is a panel component <div ng-transclude></div></div> '
```

i.e. If you want the button in the panel, and the panel text also showing in the panel.

btw., I dont know yet why.